# Epic Mickey platform

Tags: epic-mickey

Whilst Epic Mickey is coming out on Wii, does anyone know if this is a Wii exclusive, or if it is going to be ported to other consoles or pc...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2009/10/28/epic-mickey-was-originally-an-epic-pc-ps3-and-xbox-360-game/), it was originally going to be a PC/Xbox/PS3 game, but development shifted to making it Wii exclusive. It sounds like the developers focused on making the game specifically for the Wii's control scheme at that point, which reduces the chances of it being released for other platforms. (That said, a mouse and a Wiimote aren't that different, and the Xbox and PS3 both have motion controls now; I wouldn't rule out a port, but I wouldn't expect one, either, especially since they've probably made all the art assets with the Wii's hardware in mind.)